# It makes up for flaws in him vs flaws in his characteristic

Tags: grammar, meaning

So basically I have no idea if these two sentences have any difference

1. So it makes up for flaws in him
2. So it makes up for flaws in his 
   characteristic

If these are saying the same thing I'm happy cause I really don't know what the differences they have in meaning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"flaws in his characteristic" is an odd and unidiomatic phrase. I would use "flaws in his character". With that change the two examples have much the same meaning. Of course, both need context to indicate what "it" refers to.

Answer (score 1):

I think both sentences are a little unnatural. Here's a better way of saying it.

> "So, that **makes up** for his **personality** flaws."

The two sentences written by you, although, unidiomatic, seem to have the same idea and meaning.

Comment: "Character" and "personality" are both abstract nouns that talk about how a person relates to the world.  "Character" is more "internal":  Does the person persevere?  Have good morals? Have good ethics?  "Personality" is more about how the person interacts with other people:  Is the person shy?  Outgoing?  A practical joker?

Comment: What should I have there then, @David Siegel, just corrected me for using the word **character** in my example sentence. 

Comment: Your example sentence is fine, either way.  We like to think that "character" is more important (in the long run) than "personality".  If so, it should be easier for a positive "characteristic" to make up for a "personality" flaw than for a "character" flaw.

Comment: "Characteristic" is a fairly general term.  It can include physical traits like height, hair color, and speed, as well as aspects of one's character or personality.